# Need to get authenticated user name from the OAuth2User in Spring Cloud Gateway routes

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud-gateway

I am a newbie to Spring Cloud Gateway. I have created a simple SCG application and my use case is to forward the authenticated username to my downstream application via http request header.

This is my SpringBoot class

```
package com.xyz;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerProperties.Jwt;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.gateway.TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.core.annotation.AuthenticationPrincipal;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.annotation.RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.user.OAuth2User;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
@SpringBootApplication
public class OracleSSOMultiplexer {

    @Autowired
    private TokenRelayGatewayFilterFactory filterFactory;




    @GetMapping("/")
    public String index(Model model,
                        @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient OAuth2AuthorizedClient authorizedClient,
                        @AuthenticationPrincipal OAuth2User oauth2User) {
        model.addAttribute("userName", oauth2User.getName());
        model.addAttribute("clientName", authorizedClient.getClientRegistration().getClientName());
        model.addAttribute("userAttributes", oauth2User.getAttributes());
        return "index";
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {

        return builder.routes()
                //.route("resource", r -> r.path("/resource")

                .route(r -> r.path("/hyperion/**")
                    .filters(f -> f.filters(filterFactory.apply())
                            .addRequestHeader("HYPLOGIN", "scott") // I need to pass the authenticated username here instead of hardcoding it
                    .addResponseHeader("hyp-response", "hyp-response-header-val"))
                .uri("http://localhost:8081/")
                .id("hyperionModule"))
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OracleSSOMultiplexer.class, args);
    }
}
```

and this my application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8080

logging:
  level:
    root: INFO
    org.springframework.web: INFO
    org.springframework.web.HttpLogging: DEBUG
    org.springframework.security: DEBUG
    org.springframework.security.oauth2: DEBUG
    org.springframework.cloud.gateway: DEBUG

spring:
  autoconfigure:
    # TODO: remove when fixed https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6314
    exclude: org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.reactive.ReactiveManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          gateway:
            provider: pingfederate
            client-id: oidchyperion
            client-secret: Lms@12345
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/gateway
            scope: openid
        provider:
          pingfederate:
            authorization-uri: https://xyz:9035/as/authorization.oauth2
            token-uri: https://xyz:9035/as/token.oauth2
            user-info-uri: https://xyz:9035/idp/userinfo.openid
            user-name-attribute: sub
            jwk-set-uri: https://xyz:9035/pf/JWKS
#  cloud:
#    gateway:
#      routes:
#        - id: resource
#          uri: http://resource:9000
#          predicates:
#            - Path=/resource
#          filters:
#            - TokenRelay=
#            - RemoveRequestHeader=Cookie
```

I am able to perform OAuth Authentication and able to display the authenticated user information using the Model at the index.html. I need now to just pass the logged in user's username (oauth2user.getName()) in the request header but I am not able to figure out.

Any help in this regards is appreciated.

Thanks,
Thani

Comment: Aren't you receiving `access_token` in each authenticated request? If yes, utilize that

Comment: I have the access token and I am able to get the authenticated user (sub) from the access token and I am able to display it in a separate page but my issue is that I need to pass the username in the http request header via the SCG route .addRequestHeader . The OAuth2User object (which has the loggedin user details) is not visible there or I dont know the step to it.

Comment: Hi All,  I resolved it by writing a separate filter class in Spring cloud Gateway

Comment: I called the filter which have posted in the answer below with this application.yml  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: hyperionModule
        uri: http://localhost:28080/
        predicates:
        - Path=/workspace/**
        filters:
        - TokenRelay=
        - AuthNUserHeaderFilterFactory=Proxy-Remote-User

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.likeminds.filter;

import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GatewayFilter;
import 
org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.AbstractGatewayFilterFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AuthNUserHeaderFilterFactory extends 
AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<AuthNUserHeaderFilterFactory.Config> {

    private static final String VALUE = "value";

    public AuthNUserHeaderFilterFactory() {
        super(Config.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Config newConfig() {
        return new Config();
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> shortcutFieldOrder() {
        return Collections.singletonList(VALUE);
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        //Custom Pre Filter. Suppose we can extract JWT and perform 
Authentication
        return (exchange, chain) -> exchange.getPrincipal()
                .map(Principal::getName)
                .defaultIfEmpty("Default User")
                .map(userName -> {
                  //adds header to proxied request
                    System.out.println("Config value ="+config.value);
                  exchange.getRequest().mutate().header(config.value, 
userName).build();
                  System.out.println("Config First pre header filter" + 
exchange.getRequest().getHeaders());
                  return exchange;
                })
                .flatMap(chain::filter);

    }

    public static class Config {
        private String value;

        public String getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple gateway filter config and intercept the request before passing the request to downstream microservices if you are using it as a gateway.

If you are using OAuth2 Authentication then you should be able to get the users information by adding below lines of code:

```
         if (principal instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken) {
            //Get username from Principal
            String userName = principal.getName();
            
            //Get user infor from spring security context
            SecurityContextImpl context = exchange.getSession().block().getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT");
            DefaultOidcUser principal1 = (DefaultOidcUser) context.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            String fullName = principal1.getUserInfo().getFullName();
            String emailId = principal1.getUserInfo().getEmail();
        }
```

Once you get the use information, you can add this information in the request header or in cookies and pass on to the downstream microservices.

```
            // Adding cookies
            session = new HttpCookie("SESSION", exchange.getSession().block().getId()).toString();

            // adds header to proxied request
            exchange.getRequest().mutate().header("X-Auth-Username", new String[] { userName })
                .header("X-Auth-Userid", new String[] { userId })
                .header("X-Auth-Email", new String[] { emailId }).header("cookie", session)
                .build();
```

Below is complete code which you can use:

```
import java.net.HttpCookie;

import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.GlobalFilter;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl;
import 
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.DefaultOidcUser;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Configuration
public class GatewayConfig {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Bean
public GlobalFilter customGlobalFilter() {
    return (exchange, chain) -> exchange.getPrincipal().map(principal -> {

        String emailId = "";
        String session = "";
        String userName = "";

        if (principal instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken) {
            //Get username from Principal
            userName = principal.getName();
            
            SecurityContextImpl context = exchange.getSession().block().getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT");
            DefaultOidcUser principal1 = (DefaultOidcUser) context.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            emailId = principal1.getUserInfo().getEmail();
            

            // Adding cookies
            session = new HttpCookie("SESSION", exchange.getSession().block().getId()).toString();

        } 
        // adds header to proxied request
        exchange.getRequest().mutate().header("X-Auth-Username", new String[] { userName })
                .header("X-Auth-Email", new String[] { emailId }).header("cookie", session)
                .build();
        return exchange;
    }).flatMap(chain::filter).then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {

    }));
  }
}
```

You can use these headers and cookies in all the downstream microservices.